# Functions that calculates a filter mask of size NXN and applies it to an input image I using conv2() function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

I am trying to write a function to create a filter mask of size NXN and then apply it to an image read in. Here is my attempt...

```
function Iout = noiseReduction(I, N)
image = imread(I);
figure(3)
subplot(2,1,1), imshow(image), title('Original Image', 'FontSize', 15);

mask = ones(3,3) * N;
Iout = conv2(image, mask);
subplot(2,1,2), imshow(uint8(Iout)), title('Blurred Image', 'FontSize', 15);

end
```

However, when I run the function I don't get any output in `Blurred Image` I just get a blank square. Can anyone help me figure out what is wrong with this? Any help would be fantastic.

Answer (score 1):

```
mask = ones(3,3) * N;
```

This is not a NxN filter, but a 3x3 filter where each element has a value of `N`.

By convolving with such a filter, you obtain an image with very large values. You later cast this to uint8, clamping all values to 255. Hence the image looks all white.

Instead, define your kernel as:

```
mask = ones(N,N) / N^2;
```

Now `mask` is NxN and sums to 1, meaning that the output will remain in the same range as the input.

Comment: @ChrisLuengo this makes a lot more sense now thanks! :)